# Writing data to Google Fit API with Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-fit

Is there a way to write data to Google Fit using flutter? I tried Google API package for that but the documentation is for native android app and not flutter. Is there an example for that in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter is not supported by Google Fit natively, but you can use Google Fit [Rest API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest) in Flutter. Also found this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/health/example) that could help.